# How can I change the Index of an Array inside a Zip function in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iphone, swiftui

I have zipped my array of Strings and I don't know how to change the index of an array inside a zip Function in order to show the right image to the user.

Indeed, when the user chooses any row the same images are shown images[0].imagesString.

I want to show different images according to each row: When the row named super balloon is tapped, it shows an image of a balloon and superman, when sky good is tapped it shows an image of the sky and a  thumb up tapped.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you so much :)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImageInTheScreen:Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let imagesString:[String]
    let colorString: [Color]
    let rowString:String
}

class  ViewModel{
    
    var images:[ImageInTheScreen] = [ImageInTheScreen(imagesString: ["super", "baloon"], colorString: [.red,.blue],rowString: " Super Baloon"),ImageInTheScreen(imagesString: ["sky","good"], colorString: [.red,.blue],rowString: "Sky good")]
    
    var arrayForLoop : [(String,Color)] {

//when the user chooses any row the same images are shown images[0].imagesString. 

        let result =
            zip(images[0].imagesString,images[0].colorString)
        
        return result.map{($0.0,$0.1)}
        
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let vm:ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            
            List {
                ForEach(vm.images) { sentence in
                    
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: QuestionView(),
                        label: {
                            Text(sentence.rowString)
                        })
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct QuestionView:View {
    let vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View{
        
        HStack{
            ForEach(vm.arrayForLoop, id:\.0, content: {
                image in
                
                Image(image.0)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 140, height: 140)
                    .scaledToFit()
            })
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(vm: ViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `arrayForLoop`. Just pass `sentence` to `QuestionView` and then in `QuestionView` you can use `ForEach(sentence.imagesString...`

Comment: Thank you so much ! Can you explain to me how to pass sentence to QuestionView?

Comment: `QuestionView(sentence:sentence)` and then in `QuestionView` declare `var sentence: ImageInTheScreen`.

Comment: Wow I just learn something today. thank you !